# Dart running using 12 GB of memory

Tags: visual-studio-code, dart

[image]
I am using 16 GB RAM on my Pc.
This started happening while working without any reason as, far as I no.
This always happens if i start VS Code. VS Code shows analysing in the bottom bar. Something like searching or go to definition don't work.

I also deleted windows and reinstalled it, with all required programms for programming flutter.

Anyone an idea whats the problem is?

Link to sourcecode of my current project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Tk1GEuLKml0MJvFWP916Zszkeo-dpioe/view?usp=sharing

VS Code Extensions are:
- Dart Plugin
- Flutter Plugin
- Matrial Icon Pack

Flutter 0.9.4 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f37c235c32 (3 weeks ago) • 2018-09-25 17:45:40 -0400
Engine • revision 74625aed32
Tools • Dart 2.1.0-dev.5.0.flutter-a2eb050044

VS Code Version is: 1.28.1

Comment: I noticed something similar yesterday except it was the CPU. Two cores were at ~100% for a long time and it turned out being `dart` processes. I don't know exactly what. I had several VS Code windows open and one of the `webdev serve` commands got orphaned somehow. Anyway `sudo killall dart` fixed my issue.

Comment: Don't helped my out, but for others, to who want to follow this: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34802

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error.

Just execute `flutter clean`

For more information: 
[Dart consuming high cpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53075228/dart-consuming-high-cpu/61925291#61925291)

Comment: This is weird, how a clean command decrease memory usage and cpu usage of all subsequent builds for even trivial projects ?

Comment: This is only a temporary "solution", and works only for the current build.Problem resurfaces after subsequent builds

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you hit a bug in the analyzer like this one:

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34850

If you're still seeing this issue on the latest version of the SDK, please open a new issue on GitHub.