# Dart consuming high cpu

Tags: visual-studio-code, dart, flutter

In vscode everything perfect for other language but when writing dart file it consumes high cpu. Reinstalling is also not working .

> it takes almost complete ram

I am using windows as my working environment. After opening a flutter file in vscode, the the dart file consumes almost 2 GB of my ram so fast that my laptop freezes and i have to force shutdown my laptop.

Comment: it's the dart extension. In linux you can `killall dart` and it will ask to be restarted. It asks to be restarted many times repeatedly. Something with the analyzer freezing up or running away. If it can spawn multiple analyzers it would appear that it then turns itself into a fork bomb.

Comment: By chance have you previously fixed an error message in VS Code that says something like "Too many files open" and tells you how to increase the max number of files that can be watched?

Comment: Looks like it is related to https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/317

Comment: Could also be https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23155 switching to `master` or `dev` channel might help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dart running using 12 GB of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52825409/dart-running-using-12-gb-of-memory)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error.

Just run `flutter clean`

For more information: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/40243

That worked out for me.

Comment: seems like worked for me as well. CPU usage for dart process go down from 99% to 0.4%

Answer (score 0):

> Solved

It is due to type error while passing data from one file class to another file class.